# Close ssh session that has ControlPersist and is kept alive in the background

Tags: ssh, configuration

I have `ControlPersist 4h` in my `.ssh/config` and it works perfectly,
Every now and then I need to connect to this server that requires some special authentication, and if I don't use that account for while it locks my account,

the problem happens like this, I don't use my account for a while, then I ssh into the server, it checks and my account is locked so it says so but it does not actually kick me out, so if I go away (Ctrl-D, or closing the terminal) and contact the admin to unlock my account and try to connect again, my session is "kept alive" on my end and it basically does not try again, unless I reboot, or kill all ssh related processes, which is annoying,

Is there a way to close these sessions which are living in the background?

Comment: Do you mean you want to exchange running `kill <process>` with running `<close_command> <process>`? Aren't you still just running a command? I don't understand what the difference is.

Comment: I don't want to kill the ssh process, as I usually have multiple ssh connections at the same time, and I am not sure even killing the ssh process closes the sessions that are kept alive with the `ControlPersist` thing, there should be a way to ask ssh to close these.

Answer (score 9):

You want the `-O exit` option to ssh.

```
krall@localhost $ ssh -o ControlPersist=yes otherbox
Password:
krall@otherbox $ exit
Shared connection to otherbox closed
krall@localhost $ ssh otherbox -O exit
```

Another option is `-O stop`, which makes the control master stop accepting connections, or close if nothing is currently connected.

Comment: So I cannot do it from within the remote device on which I am currently ssh'ed? (Closing it when leaving seems more intuitive to me than having to ssh back in just to close it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you `ps -ef | grep {hostname}` of the connection, you can then `kill -9` the process and it will reset the connection.

Comment: so basically you are saying `ControlPersist` works only by keeping the ssh processes running in the background?